# Why does my ImageView get a 1 pixel height using ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**UPDATED**
I took the sample layout that was posted by @theThapa that seemed to work, and made two edits to it: I took out the android:tint lines, and I substituted a single vector drawable for the three drawables in the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/media_audio_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/linked_hands_transluscent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionButtonsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topImageView"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/deleteSaveCancelContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMessage"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            tools:text="delete"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            tools:text="save"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            tools:text="cancel"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actionButtonsContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="Press the Microphone to record your description. Press the Play and Stop buttons to review your recording"/>
```

I don't see the proper results like what was posted as an answer below. I really wonder if the difference is in the Android Studio and/or ConstraintLayout versions in play (I am using the latest ConstraintLayout- 2.0.0-alpha5)

Portrait:
[image]

Landscape:
[image]

**UPDATED**
I have found that if i "pre-load" an image into the ImageView then swap out the image for the real one I want, then the layout gets done appropriately. I still think that feels like a work-around that I shouldn't have to do, but at least I got that part working.

Now the second part of my post - where the landscape orientation doesn't layout correctly is still an issue. Why is it behaving that way?

**Original Post**
I am using ConstraintLayout to design a screen that shows an AppCompatImageView, a divider line, some buttons for recording/playing audio and some buttons for delete/save/cancel. In Android Studio, the preview looks fine:

[image]

However at runtime, I get no visible image at all. The loadImageIntoImageView() method used to load the image into the ImageView is working correctly in other contexts with this same image, so I believe it is something to do with ConstraintLayout. I have put in logging like this:

```
    AppCompatImageView view = findViewById(R.id.media_image_view);
    InTouchUtils.loadImageIntoImageView(pathToMedia, this, view);
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // Make sure the new entry is visible
            Timber.d("Lifecycle: ImageView size is: w:%d, h:%d", view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

        }
    });
```

and it appears that the ImageView is being given the full width (1440 pixels) of the device I am testing on (Samsung S7 Edge), but only 1 pixel height:

[image]

The other thing I don't understand is that when I change orientation to landscape in Android Studio, the preview result is not at all what I expected (and is not what actually happens on the device either - I get the same result as in portrait orientation):

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/media_audio_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/media_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/grandparents_grandchildren_transluscent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/annotation_controls_separator"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        tools:ignore="all" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/annotation_controls_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progress_recording_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_image_view" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/progress_recording_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/media_buttons_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/media_buttons_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/media_buttons_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/annotation_controls_separator">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/audioProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/recordingLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/text_margin_small"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/text_margin_small"
            android:text="@string/media_recording_label"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/media_buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/media_buttons_explanation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress_recording_layout">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_record_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_media_record_start"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_media_record_play"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_24dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/media_stop_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_media_record_stop"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_stop_black_24dp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/media_buttons_explanation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/text_margin_small"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/text_margin_small"
        android:text="@string/media_record_explanation_label"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_buttons_layout" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dismissButtons"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/media_buttons_explanation" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/dismissButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontal_view1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_view2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/recording_delete_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/media_delete_label" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/recording_save_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/media_save_label" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/recording_cancel_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/media_cancel_label" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dismissButtons" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I feel like I must be doing something obviously wrong, but I just can't see it.

Comment: I think it's because you're using android:layout_width="0dp", try putting a value for it.

Comment: No - in a ConstraintsLayout, 0dp means "match constraints". I have the constraints set to the start/end of parent, which is why my log statement is printing out that the image is 1440 wide. Even if I set the constraint for the bottom of the image to bottom of parent (effectively breaking the chain), I still get a height of 1 pixel at runtime reported for the ImageView.

Comment: removing `tools:ignore="all"` might tell you what is wrong with the constraints.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - that's an interesting idea - but removed it - no visible impact, and did a full build am not seeing anything odd.

Comment: @MartinZeitler @tfrysinger `tools` tag is just for design previews. So, it doesn't solve the problem you are having. `tools:ignore="all"` is just ignoring the warnings.

Comment: @theThapa but these warning are often about constraints... while I'd rather wonder, why even a `ConstraintLayout`, for something that quite looks alike a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler If the warning are about the `ConstraintLayout`, we have to address those, not ignore. We get those warnings if we missed to add `constraint` to any child view in a ConstraintLayout. In most cases we should at least address these `top, start, bottom, end`. If the warning is like `ContentDescription` missing in `ImageView`, in almost all cases we can do `tools:ignore="ContentDescription`.

Answer (score 0):

@tfrysinger please refer to the below `xml`. I have attached the screenshots as well.Formatting isn't the best, please don't mind.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     
      android:id="@+id/media_audio_root_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="16dp"
      >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_file"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionButtonsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topImageView"
        >

         <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:tint="@color/gray_dark"
          tools:src="@drawable/ic_file"
          tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
          />

        <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
          android:tint="@color/gray_dark"
          tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
          tools:src="@drawable/settings_icon"
        />

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:tint="@color/gray_dark"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_sync"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/deleteSaveCancelContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="center"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMessage"
      >

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:tint="@color/gray_dark"
        tools:text="delete"
        />

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
         android:id="@+id/btnSave"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         android:tint="@color/gray_dark"
         tools:text="save"
         />

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
         android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         android:tint="@color/gray_dark"
         tools:text="cancel"
      />

  </LinearLayout>

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actionButtonsContainer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:text="Press the Microphone to record your description. Press the Play and Stop buttons to review your recording"
    />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to play with this - a couple comments - I have learned the hard way to not hard-wire sizes if at all possible. Too many variations out there with various resolutions, it is much better to auto-size to fit the device. But the significant thing is I took your layout, substituted vector drawables I have for the icons you reference, and I'm still seeing the same problem in landscape! I am using the 3.4 release version of Studio, and constraintlayout 2.0.0-alpha4. I just upgraded to alpha5, no difference.

Comment: @tfrysinger I just left the hardcoded dimensions for you to change/update as per your requirement. As you saw in the screenshots, I tried both portrait/ landscape and it works. Please give me your specific preview specs  or the device specs you are using to test and I will try it with that specifications.

Comment: I edited my question so I could post example images of what I get when I use your XML, see above. I have gotten similar results on 6 emulators of varying types, and on S2 and S3 Samsung tablets and my Samsung S7 Edge handset. What version of Android Studio and ConstraintLayout are you using?

Comment: @tfrysinger I am using `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"` version of `ConstraintLayout`. Landscape isn't working for you because of your device specs. You need to wrap that layout in `ScrollView`. Please refer to the updated xml. I have also attached a preview screenshot as per your device specs. The dotted lines refer to the views layout out, but will only be visible when scrolled. 
And I am not completely sure why your layout aren't working with the `TouchUtils`.

Comment: I don't understand why I should have to wrap it in a ScrollView. There is nothing that is specifying a minimum size for the ImageView that is too large - in fact I specifically indicated to constrain the height as necessary according to the ConstraintLayout docs by indicating android:layout_height="wrap_content" and then app:layout_constrainedHeight="true". To me this should cause it to reduce the height accordingly in order to fit all the components.

Comment: The ImageView's height is set to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` -> this means if the image being loaded is bigger, the ImageView's dimensions will increate and if smaller, the dimensions will decrease. If we load bigger image, other views below the `ImageView` will be pushed below the viewport and will be cut off. That is why we need to wrap in `ScrollView`. Further you can play around with the `layout_height` attribute of ImageView with `50dp`, `100dp`, `150dp` to see the layout behavior.

Comment: That's what constrainedHeight is supposed to take care of. Take a look at the docs, at least as they are written it states that even though you indicate wrap_content, it is still supposed to constrain the height within the constraints I've set. It isn't. In fact you *only* use constrainedHeight in the case where you have also indicated wrap_content. It's supposed to work like "wrap content but also constrain the height as I have indicated". It just isn't doing it.

Comment: Youa are right, the docs mentions that `constrainedHeight` should work with `wrap_content`. I tried your layout with multiple of those options. The only way I could get the layout to work as per your requirement was wrapping it with `ScrollView`. I am not sure why `constrainedHeight` isn't working when the docs says it should work.

Comment: Yeah, hence my post :)  I think it is a bug. I ended up solving this by including a horizontal guideline at 50%, and constraining the image to always be in the top half of the layout by making it's bottomToTopOf constraint = "horizontalGuideline"

Comment: It sure sounds like a bug :), I am glad you figured it out with guidelines.